# Excel VBA for searching in mails of Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I'm working on a project where I have a list of Account IDs, and what I'm trying to do is to create a macro that will interface with Outlook, search my Inbox for any email with an specific criteria, and then return "Y" or "N" if it was found, and if it was found, who the email was sent from and the time it was sent. Below is the code I'm using; I need the macro to search the Body of the Email instead of the Subject Line. When I substitute [Subject] for [Body], the macro runs without errors, but returns no emails (I place a couple test emails for it to catch). I am running Excel and Outlook 2007, and have already reference the MS 12.0 Excel & Outlook libraries in VBA.

```
Sub Work_with_Outlook()

    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olMail As Variant
    Dim sir() As String

    Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myTasks = Fldr.Items

    Set olMail = myTasks.Find("[Subject] = ""123456""")
    If Not (olMail Is Nothing) Then
        olMail.Display
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861580(v=office.14).aspx for filtering the body

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot use Body in Find(Filter), see [Items.Find Method (Outlook)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662.aspx),
as a Workaround, you can use VBA string search function:

```
Sub sofWorkWithOutlook20082550()
  Dim outlookApp
  Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
  Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim olMail As Variant
  Dim myTasks
  Dim sir() As String

  'Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
  Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  Set olNs = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  Set myTasks = Fldr.Items

  '
  'Set olMail = myTasks.Find("[Subject] = ""123456""")
  '
  For Each olMail In myTasks
  '
    If (InStr(1, olMail.Body, "My-Text-to-Search", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
      olMail.Display
      Exit For
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much jacouh! I tried running your code, but it didn't return anything; no error, no email to display. I changed `olMail.display` to `Msgbox "This worked"` but nothing happened. Any ideas?

Comment: Please change "My-Text-to-Search" to some string you have in your email... and re-try it.