# Display multiple related results from Outlook search

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

The code found in this thread works fine for single email results: [Excel VBA for searching in mails of Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082550/excel-vba-for-searching-in-mails-of-outlook), But it only returns the latest email.

Is it possible to adjust the code to display more than 1 result?

The code that I have from the thread is:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub search_outlook()

    Dim outlookapp
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olMail As Variant
    Dim myTasks

    Dim projIDsearch As String

    projIDsearch = ActiveCell.Cells(1, 4)
    Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    'Set outlookapp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = outlookapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("ExemptionReview")
    Set myTasks = Fldr.Items

    For Each olMail In myTasks
        If (InStr(1, olMail.Subject, projIDsearch, vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
            olMail.Display
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `Exit For`. This drops out of the loop when a match is found:

```
olMail.Display  
Exit For       '<Remove this
```