# Outlook VBA Incorrectly Replying to Emails in Folder

Tags: vba, email, outlook

As referenced from this post, [Excel VBA for searching in mails of Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082550/excel-vba-for-searching-in-mails-of-outlook), I changed the code slightly to resend all emails to the same recipient in the "sent items" folder.

```
Function ReplyEmail()

    Dim olMail
    Dim olMails

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    Set olMails = olFldr.Items

    For Each olMail In olMails

        olMail.ReplyAll
        olMail.Importance = 2
        olMail.Subject = "RE: 2ND " & olMail.Subject
        olMail.Send

    Next olMail

End Function
```

However, for some strange reason, this function sends only **half** of all emails in designated folder. If there are 9 emails, the function sends out 5 (4 left), then if I run another iteration, the function sends out 2, and so on...

If I change `olMail.Send` to `olMail.Display`, then the function displays **all** emails in pop-up frames.

Has any one encountered this issue or know what's the reason behind it?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could iterate through the names of the subjects of the emails in olmails, just to see what its holdings

Comment: I replaced `olMail.Send` with `MsgBox (olMail.To)` and **all emails** are displayed. However, it's only when the line `olMail.Send` appears that this issue occurs. If I add in `MsgBox (olMail.To)` **before** `olMail.Send` then only **half ** of all emails' recipients are displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, I don't understand why you are not using the MailItem object returned from the ReplyAll method to set the properties and call .Send on that object and not the copy of the sent item represented by your olMail variable.

Otherwise I suspect the collection of items is changing.  Change the For Each to a For with a reverse counter loop and the weirdness should go away.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know `Mailitem.ReplyAll` returns a new MailItem. Now that I think about it, your second statement makes sense as well.